# Inserting new rows to dataframe without losing format

Tags: r, dataframe, insertion

I am trying to create a large empty data.frame and insert a groups of row. I have seen a few similar questions on numerous forums, however I have been unable to apply any of them successfully to the specific formatting issue I am having.

I started with rbind(df,allic) # allic is the data frame I would like to insert into df # however, given the size of my dataset the operation takes 5 1/2 minutes to complete. I understand that creating the data frame at the beginning and replacing rows improves efficiency, however I have been unable to make it work for my problem. Code is as follows:

Initial data:

```
  Order.ID                  Product
1    193505              Onion Rings
2    193505 Pineapple Cheddar Burger
3    193623            Fountain Soda
4    193623             French Fries
5    193623                Hamburger
6    193623                  Hot Dog
7    193631             French Fries
8    193631                Hamburger
9    193631                Milkshake
```

The products won't match to below, however this being a formatting issue I figured it best to show the formatting that brought me to where I am now.

```
nb$Order.ID <- as.factor(nb$Order.ID)
plist <- aggregate(nb$Product,list(nb$Order.ID),list)
allp <- unique(unlist(plist$x))
allic <- expand.grid(plist$x[[1]], Var2=plist$x[[1]], Var3=1)


                      Var1                     Var2 Var3
1              Onion Rings              Onion Rings    1
2 Pineapple Cheddar Burger              Onion Rings    1
3              Onion Rings Pineapple Cheddar Burger    1
4 Pineapple Cheddar Burger Pineapple Cheddar Burger    1
```

Now I create an empty dataframe (df) using:

```
df <- data.frame(factor=rep(NA, rcnt), factor=rep(NA,rcnt), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

rcnt being a large, arbitrary number which I plan to trim once the operation is complete. My issue comes when I try to insert these lines using:

```
df[1:4,] <- allic
head(df, n=10)


  factor factor.1
1      47       47
2      51       47
3      47       51
4      51       51
5      NA       NA
6      NA       NA
7      NA       NA
8      NA       NA
```

How can I insert rows in a dataframe without losing the format of my values? I would greatly appreciate any help I can get at this point.

**EDIT** Per comment below:

```
>df[i] <- for(i in 1:nrow(plist)) {
>       allic <- expand.grid(plist$x[[i]], Var2=plist$x[[i]], Var3=1) 
>       df[i:nrow(allic),] <- sapply(allic, as.character)
```

I'm still very new with R, however this was working when I was using df <- rbind(df,allic). nrow(df) is 4096.

Comment: Hi @LFoos24, it's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish, but  I'm guessing there might be other ways to go about it.

Comment: @ Ricardo I am sure you are correct in that assertion. Again, I am fairly new to this and hacking together what I can to make this work. What I am trying to accomplish is loop over all the orders to get all combinations of items that are ordered together, mark each with a 1, and add up the combinations to show the count for every combination. Hopefully that helps to some degree.

Comment: it might be helpful to open up a new question explaining simply that you want to count all combinations of items that are ordered together,  explain what you've tried and ask if there might be more effective ways to go about it.  There are some really smart folks on here who I'm sure would be willing to give some helpful advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping allic in `as.character` as follows:

```
df[1:4,] <- sapply(allic, as.character)


> df
                     factor                 factor.1
1               Onion Rings              Onion Rings
2  Pineapple Cheddar Burger              Onion Rings
3               Onion Rings Pineapple Cheddar Burger
4  Pineapple Cheddar Burger Pineapple Cheddar Burger
5                      <NA>                     <NA>
6                      <NA>                     <NA>
7                      <NA>                     <NA>
8                      <NA>                     <NA>
9                      <NA>                     <NA>
10                     <NA>                     <NA>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you. Any idea why when I substituted this into my loop (df <- rbind(df,allic) ---->> df[i:nrow(allic),] <- sapply(allic, as.character)) I get the error " new columns would leave holes after existing columns"?

Comment: What is the value of i?  what is the value of nrow(df)?